# JS. Как удалить <aside data-sidebar></aside> оставив все что внутри?

Tags: javascript

Есть часть кода html (фильтр товара), он размещен внутри

```
<aside data-sidebar>HTML и PHP содержимое филтра товаров</aside>
```

aside data-sidebar, мне нужен чисто для мобильных. А вот для ПК мне не нужен этот aside, так как он выводит левый слайд.

Думаю с помощью JS удалить  при условии. Но не знаю как это удалить, оставив все что внутри него.
Прошу помочь.

Как то так...

```
var x = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if (x <='950') {
удалить  <aside data-sidebar></aside>
}
```

Comment: Если используете jquery - $('ид вашего контента').unwrap();

Comment: Use the [Media Queries](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media), Luke!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var el = document.querySelector('aside');
var parent = el.parentNode;
var x = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

if (x >='950') {
  while (el.firstChild) parent.insertBefore(el.firstChild, el);
  parent.removeChild(el);
}
```

```css
aside {color:red;}
div {color:blue;}
```

```html
<div>
  <aside data-sidebar>HTML и PHP содержимое фильтра товаров</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Не работает. может потому что JS в aside добавляет еще стили?
например: 
<aside data-sidebar="" style="margin-left: -200px; overflow: hidden; display: block; transition: all 0.2s ease;">

Comment: Стоп, только сейчас заметил. Если для пк нужно убрать aside, то тут условие должно быть другим. Вместо `x <= '950'` должно быть `x >= '950'`.

Comment: Условие да, так работает. но aside не вырезается..

Answer (score 0):

Можно решить проблему с помощью медиа-запроса в css:

```
@media (max-width: 760px){
  aside[data-sidebar]{
    display: none;
  }
}
```